# key/value map to mysql procedure from django

Tags: python, mysql, django, stored-procedures

I have a key/value map in session of my django web app. Example:

```
3 = YES
4 = NO
9 = YES
```

I would like to pass these keys and values to a mysql procedue. What would be the best way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL does not support passing arrays to a stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-17), so you cannot do this directly.

If the maximum value for the key is known, you can create a stored procedure with many arguments. In your example, you can create a procedure with 9 parameters, pass YES for the third and the ninth parameter, NO for the fourth and NULL for the rest. Ugly, but it works.

If you cannot do it, then you can create a new table, with the session id, the key and the value as columns, and pass the session id as the parameter to your stored procedure. Then you can SELECT the key/values inside your stored procedure.

Comment: Creating new table with session_id and values and then passing it as an argument to procedure is the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can [execute sql queries directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) with django.